# Finding motifs and position of motif in FASTA file - Perl

Tags: loops, perl, position, fasta

Can someone help me with this Perl code? When I run it, nothing happens. No errors or anything which is weird to me. It reads in and opens the file just fine. I believe the problem is in the while loop or the foreach loop cause I honestly don't think I understand them. I'm very new at this with a pretty shit teacher.

Instructions: Declare a scalar variable called motif and make it AAA. Declare an array variable called locations, which is where the locations of the motif will be stored. Place the gene in a scalar variable. Now search for that motif in the amborella gene. The code should print the position of the motif and the motif found. You will need to write a while loop that searches for the motif and includes push, pos, and –length commands in order to save and report locations. Then you will need a foreach loop to print the locations and the motif. (If it only reports locations in the first line of the gene, remember that is because the gene is in a scalar variable that will only read the first line. That is acceptable.

My code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

#Declare a scalar variable called motif and make it AAA.
my$motif="AAA";

#Declare an array variable called locations, which is where the
#locations of the motif will be stored.
my@locations=();
my$foundMotif="";
my$position=();

#Place the gene in a scalar variable.
my$geneFileName = 'amborella.txt';
open(GENEFILE, $geneFileName) or die "Can't read file!";
my$gene = <GENEFILE>;

#Now search for that motif in the amborella gene.
#The code should print the position of the motif and the motif
#found. You will need to write a while loop that searches for the
#motif and includes push, pos, and –length commands in order to
#save and report locations.

while($foundMotif =~ m/AAA/g) {
$position=(pos($foundMotif)-3);
push (@locations, $position);
}

#Then you will need a foreach loop to print the locations and the motif.
foreach $position (@locations){
print "\n Found motif: ", $motif, "\n at position: ", $position;
}

#close the file
close GENEFILE;

exit;
```

Comment: We're somewhere between Stack Overflow and Code Review right now. I have some comments on your style, which is probably down to  outdated teaching material. It's good that you have `strict` and `warnings`. Those are helpful.  But you should indent your code as well, that'll make it easier to read. Your `open` call has some problems, but they're not the cause of your code not doing what you want (look up _3 argument open_ if you're interested).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is fine, it's a simple mix-up.

You are matching against an empty string.

```
while($foundMotif =~ m/AAA/g) {
  $position = (pos($foundMotif)-3);
  push (@locations, $position);
}
```

You're looking for `AAA` in `$foundMotif`. But that's an empty string because you just declared it further up. Your gene string (disclaimer: I know nothing about bio informatics) is `$gene`. That's what you need to match.

---

Let's go through it step by step. I've simplified your code and put in an example string. I'm aware that isn't what genes look like, but that doesn't matter. This is already fixed.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $motif = "AAA";

my @locations  = ();

# ... skip reading the file
my $gene = "ABAABAAABAAAAB\n";

while ($gene =~ m/$motif/g) {                     # 1, 2
    my $position = (pos($gene) - length($motif)); # 3, 4
    push(@locations, $position);
}

foreach $position (@locations) {
    print "\n Found motif: ", $motif, "\n at position: ", $position;
}
```

If you run this, the code now produces meaningful output.

```
 Found motif: AAA
 at position: 5
 Found motif: AAA
 at position: 9
```

I've made four changes:

1. You need to search in `$gene`
2. Your variable `$motif` is meaningless if you don't use it to search. That way, your program becomes dynamic.
3. Again, you need to use the `pos()` in `$gene`
4. To make it dynamic, you shouldn't hard-code the [`length`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/length.html)

You don't need the `$foundMotif` variable at all. The `$position` can actually be *lexical* to the block it's in. That means, it will be a different variable each time the loop is run, which is simply good practice. In Perl, you want to always use the smallest [*scope*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)) possible for variables, and declare them only when you need them, not in advance.

Since this is a learning exercise, it makes sense to iterate the array separately. In a real life program, you could eliminate the `foreach` loop and the array and output the positions directly if you were not to use them later on.

Comment: Thanks so much. Yea because of covid the level of teaching in detail has kinda gone out the window and I'm pretty lost in this class, this is my first intro to Perl. I'm still a bit confused as to why I need the - length($motif). What is that telling us?

Comment: @amanda [`length`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/length.html) gives you the number of characters in that string. Because your motif is in a variable, it's dynamic. You could pass it in as an argument to your program as well, to search for arbitrary motifs. But if the motif is not `AAA`, but say `GAGAGAGA`, it'll be longer than 3 chars, so this needs to be dynamic, depending on the actual motif used.

Comment: If you'd like to look at Perl a bit more, I suggest you use a modern resource for that. There are not many fancy online resources compared to Python unfortunately, but some are available. I'd probably get the O'Reilly _Learning Perl_ book (one of the authors is a regular here, too), or if you know a little bit about programming, Curtis Poe's _Beginning Perl_. I don't know much about what you would need exactly for bioinformatics as I work in the web world, but those should both be solid foundations to build upon, especially if your teaching materials are a bit dusty.

Comment: Feel free to ask more questions. :)